# How to read frequently contacts in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to get frequently called list. CONTENT_STREQUENT_URI gives you starred and frequently and i want just frequently.

Cursor  c = this.getContentResolver (). query (Contacts.CONTENT_STREQUENT_URI,
            null, null, null,null);

Comment: tried to "filter out" `ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED` items?

Comment: can you give me some idea how to filter the result.Actually i got the frequent and starred contacts but on a lenevo device if i cleared the frequent calls native app doesn't show any frequent call but my app still give the frequent contacts. I am confused what should i do

Comment: see 3rd an 4th parameter of `query` method

Answer (score 0):

This may help you in getting frequent/starred contacts that you are searching for. I wrote the getPhoneNumbers method out for you as an example of how to pull the information out of the cursor. Also, note that if you remove the contacts from your device/ unstar them, this will not automatically update your ui. You will need to resync your data. To do this, there are a few ways. In my opinion, if you just refetch this data again it won't be too bad, as you probably don't have too many starred contacts. But for bigger input size, you will want to paginate this list and find a more elegant way than fetching this data every time.

```
    public static List<? extends ContactsModel> getFreqContacts(Context context) {
        List<ContactsModel> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, "starred=?", new String[]{"1"}, "upper(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");

        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                final String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                final Set<String> phone_numbers = getContactPhoneNumber(contentResolver, cursor, contact_id);
                final Set<String> emails = getContactEmailAddress(contentResolver, contact_id);

                 // do whatever you want. Now you have the phone numbers and emails of the contacts you want
             }
         }
         cursor.close();

         Collections.sort(faveContactsModels);
         return faveContactsModels;
     }

    private static Set<String> getContactPhoneNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver, Cursor cursor,String id) {
        Set<String> contactNumbers = new HashSet<>();
        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0
            ) {
             Cursor pCur = contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "= ?",
                new String[]{id}, null
            );
            while(pCur.moveToNext()) {
                 String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                contactNumbers.add(phoneNo);
            }
            pCur.close();
        }
        return contactNumbers;
    }
```

Comment: this will give me only starred contacts i need frequently dialed number

Comment: Is there any real solution for this? did you find anything? @AnkitPawar